# Java JSON array

Tags: java, arrays

I have output from url as following:

["HANK-TPSSL4-app","acgeneral-app","acgeneral-web","achalf-app","acproduct-app"]

My Java code to get each object from this array:

```
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((HttpURLConnection) alertHandleUrl.openConnection().getInputStream()));

        String output;      
        while ((output = in.readLine()) != null) {

             JSONArray array = new JSONArray(output);

                for (int i =0; i < array.length(); i++)
                    JSONObject row = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    System.out.println(row);
                }
```

The error I am getting is

Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONArray[0] is not a JSONObject.
    at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(JSONArray.java:330)
    at com.ebay.sherlock.calc.AutoConfigFunc.main(AutoConfigFunc.java:70)

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: You output should look like that {"myarray":["abc","def"]} then new JSONObject(output).getJSONArray("myarray").... And it should do it. Or try to make your output look like that {["abc","def"]} and new JSONArray(output)

Comment: Hi, Since my ouput is in the format of ["abc","def"] format, How do I get each object from this JSON array? Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this output is a simple String array not a JSON object. You need to trim the leading and trailing braces and then split the string by comma ","

Comment: Hi, My ouput is already split by comma ",". Here is my output:   ["HANK-TPSSL4-app","acgeneral-app","acgeneral-web","achalf-app","acproduct-app"]

Comment: @user2325703 yes, but it is string. You need to split it by using split() method and convert it into a String[] array